Matlab array multiply
What is the difference between multiplications * and .* in 2 arrays in matlab.
E.g. a=[1 2 3], b=[4 5 6] Error using  * when trying a * b = c c=[4 10 18]
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches theyour text number of rows in the
second matrix. To operate on each element of the matrix individually, use TIMES (.*) for elementwise multiplication.
